# Swift: How to get form values using Eureka form builder?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm building a form with the Eureka form builder but don't understand how I can get the values inside the form. [They provide instructions in the docs here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#how-to-get-the-form-values).

The form results are passed to a dictionary:

> As you may have noticed the result dictionary key is the row tag value
>   and the value is the row value. Only rows with a tag value will be
>   added to the dictionary.

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    form =

        Section()

        <<< NameRow() { // NameRow is dictionary key, right?
            $0.title = "Name:"
            $0.value = "My name" // This is what should be printed
        }

        let dict = form.values(includeHidden: true)

        // PROBLEM: This prints nil
        print(dict["NameRow"])

}
```

And here the public func that makes the dict

```
public func values(includeHidden includeHidden: Bool = false) -> [String: Any?]{
    if includeHidden {
        return allRows.filter({ $0.tag != nil })
            .reduce([String: Any?]()) {
                var result = $0
                result[$1.tag!] = $1.baseValue
                return result
        }
    }
    return rows.filter({ $0.tag != nil })
        .reduce([String: Any?]()) {
            var result = $0
            result[$1.tag!] = $1.baseValue
            return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It wasn't immediately clear to me that you need to set tags on the rows you want to retrieve the value from:

```
<<< NameRow() {
    $0.tag = "NameRow"
    $0.title = "Name:"
    $0.value = "My name"
}

let dict = form.values(includeHidden: true)

print(dict["NameRow"]) // Prints my name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another syntax to add `tag` would be to pass it within parenthesis:

```
<<< NameRow("NameRow") { // Notice the tag being passed as String
    $0.title = "Name:"
    $0.value = "My name"
}

let dict = form.values(includeHidden: true)

print(dict["NameRow"]) // Will Still Print the name
```

Reference taken from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43631097/3207014)