# Eureka : cannot convert value of type 'BaseRow?' to specified type 'CustomPushRow?'

Tags: swift, forms, generics, row, eureka-forms

I have use Eureka for my form but i am facing an issues. I setup the form using these code

```
form +++ Section("Add Event")
        <<< TextRow("Event"){ row in
            row.title = "Event"
            row.placeholder = "Enter Event Name Here"
        }
        <<< DateRow("Date"){
            $0.title = "Date"
            $0.value = selectedDate

        }
        <<< TimeRow("Time"){
            $0.title = "Time"
            $0.value = selectedDate

    }
    let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "eventLocation") as! EventLocationViewController

    form +++ Section("Location")
        <<< CustomPushRow<EventLocationViewController>(){
            $0.title = "Location"
            $0.presentationMode = .segueName(segueName: "eventLocation" ,controllerProvider: locationSearchTable, onDismiss: nil)

    }
```

here the custom push row class

```
public final class CustomPushRow<T: Equatable>: SelectorRow<PushSelectorCell<T>, SelectorViewController<T>>, RowType {

public required init(tag: String?) {
    super.init(tag: tag)
    presentationMode = .show(controllerProvider: ControllerProvider.callback {
        return SelectorViewController<T>(){ _ in }
        }, onDismiss: { vc in
            print("On Dimiss")
            _ = vc.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    })
}

}
```

and when i wanna change the value of the form i use this method to change

```
    let eventName : TextRow? = form.rowBy(tag:"Event")
    eventName?.value = "asdasadsds"
```

but when i wanna change the custom push row i am having this issues cannot convert value of type 'BaseRow?' to specified type 'CustomPushRow?' when i do this

```
   let row : CustomPushRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "Location")
```

How can i change the value of the CustomPushRow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking your info a different way (a tip I got from [Swift: How to get form values using Eureka form builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716588/swift-how-to-get-form-values-using-eureka-form-builder?rq=1) helped me with another "cannot convert value of...." issue)

To READ the value on a row that gives you the error message:

1. Be sure to set tags on all your elements ($0.tag = "whatever")
2. instead of

   let row : CustomPushRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "Location")

use

```
let dict = self.form.values(includeHidden: true)
```

Then you can see the value with something like

```
print(dict["whatever"])
```

Now, the other part of your question asked about SETTING the value, which is a different thing in Eureka.

From the docs (https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#how-to-set-the-form-values-using-a-dictionary):

> How to set the form values using a dictionary

Invoking setValues(values: [String: Any?]) which is exposed by Form class.

For example:

```
form.setValues(["IntRowTag": 8, "TextRowTag": "Hello world!", "PushRowTag": Company(name:"Xmartlabs")])
```

Where "IntRowTag", "TextRowTag", "PushRowTag" are row tags (each one uniquely identifies a row) and 8, "Hello world!", Company(name:"Xmartlabs") are the corresponding row value to assign.