# Get Form Values from Multivalued sections of Eureka Form

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

Asking this question here because this has not been covered in docs yet and they monitor and answer this tag.
I am using [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#multivalued-sections) to build a Multivalued Form.
This is my code:

```
    +++ MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Reorder, .Insert, .Delete],
        header: "Options",
        footer: "footer") {
                            $0.addButtonProvider = { section in
                                return ButtonRow(){
                                    $0.title = "Add New Option"
                                }
                            }
                            $0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in
                                print(self.form.values())
                                return NameRow() {
                                    $0.placeholder = "Your option"
                                }
                            }
                            $0 <<< NameRow() {
                                $0.placeholder = "Your option"
                            }
    }
```

Now I want to extract all the values in NameRows at the end. There can be any number of rows(based on user input). This is what I tried:

`self.form.values()`
but it results in `[ : ]`.

How do I get all the values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone with similar problem:

The `form.values()` was empty because there were no tags given to the Rows.
To get values from `form`, give tags to rows and you will get a dictionary of values with keys as these tags. For this case

```
+++ MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Reorder, .Insert, .Delete],
                           header: "header",
                           footer: "footer") {
                            $0.addButtonProvider = { section in
                                return ButtonRow(){
                                    $0.title = "Button Title"
                                }
                            }
                            $0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in
                                return NameRow("tag_\(index+1)") {
                                    $0.placeholder = "Your option"
                                }
                            }
                            $0 <<< NameRow("tag_1") {
                                $0.placeholder = "Your option"
                            }
    }
```

Now the values will be returned as `["tag_1" : "value 1", "tag 2 : "value 2" ....]` for any number of rows inserted by user.
P.S.: Used the `index` in tag because duplicate tags aren't allowed and `index` value is different for different rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler way

first of all, add a tag to the whole MultivaluedSection object.

```
    +++ MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Reorder, .Insert, .Delete],
    header: "Options",
    footer: "footer") {

                        $0.tag = "someTag" // added this line

                        $0.addButtonProvider = { section in
                            return ButtonRow(){
                                $0.title = "Add New Option"
                            }
                        }
                        $0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in
                            print(self.form.values())
                            return NameRow() {
                                $0.placeholder = "Your option"
                            }
                        }
                        $0 <<< NameRow() {
                            $0.placeholder = "Your option"
                        }
}
```

and then, you can get the values by

```
let values = (self.form.values()["someTag"]!! as! [Any?]).compactMap { $0 }
```

Comment: i got this error: Generic parameter 'ElementOfResult' could not be inferred

Answer (score 0):

The form.values() returns Dictionary, and Dictionary doesn't have order info.
So you can not get Reordered values from form.values().

I got orderd data like below:
(form.allRows returns Array, and that has order info.)

```
// Dictionary doen't have order info.
let values: Dictionary = form.values()
NSLog("LogA : %@", values)

// Array has order info, and this can return all tags.
let allRow: Array<BaseRow> = form.allRows
for i in 0..<allRow.count {
    let tmp: BaseRow = allRow[i]
    NSLog("LogB : %d : %@", i, tmp.tag ?? "")
}

// So make ordered data by from.values() and form.allRows like this.
var results: Array = [String]()
for i in 0..<allRow.count {
    let tag: String = allRow[i].tag ?? ""
    if(tag != ""){
        let val: String = values[tag] as! String
        results.append(tag + ":" + val)
    }
}
NSLog("LogC = %@", results)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37716924/1586606)
just give the tag to each row;

```
<<< NameRow() {
$0.tag = "NameRow"
$0.title = "Name:"
$0.value = "My name" }
```

Comment: The same thing is described in the answer above